# Given a list of words, for each word find the shortest unique prefix

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been practicing some coding questions and i was wondering if there was a better way to solve this problem

Given a list of words, for each word find the shortest unique prefix. You can assume a word will not be a substring of another word (ie play and playing won't be in the same words list)

Example

```
Input: ['joma', 'john', 'jack', 'techlead']
Output: ['jom', 'joh', 'ja', 't']
```

Here's some starter code:

```
def shortest_unique_prefix(words):
  # Fill this in.

print(shortest_unique_prefix(['joma', 'john', 'jack', 'techlead']))
# ['jom', 'joh', 'ja', 't']
```

here's my code:

```
def shortest_unique_prefix(words):
  # Fill this in.
  i=0
  k=0
  j=i+1
  temp=''
  while i<len(words):
    if words[i][k] == words[j][k]:
        if k == len(words[i])-1 or k == len(words[j])-1:

            words[i]=words[i][:k+1]
            i +=1
            continue

        k +=1
    else:
            if len(words[i][:k+1])>len(temp):
                temp = words[i][:k+1]
            #words[i]=words[i][:k+1]
            k=0
            j +=1
            j=j%len(words)
            if j==i:
                words[i]=temp
                temp=''
                i +=1

                if i == len(words):
                    break
                j =(i+1)%len(words)


  return words              
                


print(shortest_unique_prefix(['joma', 'john','jack','techlead']))
# ['jom', 'joh', 'ja', 't']
```

I'm getting the correct output but i was wondering if the problem could be solved in a simpler or better way

Comment: if your code works fine with no issues and you just want a review or optimization it might be better suited on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, you might also want to mention what the definition of shortest prefix is? how is it defined or measured

Comment: A possible soultion using `set`, see [Live-Demo](https://repl.it/repls/BackEffectiveEquation#main.py)